# Sum integers in tcsh/ sum string to integer

Tags: scripting, csh, tcsh

I'm new into shell and stuff, and i encountered a problem.
I have to count how many lines have the files in a directory together

with this i count the line length of each file in for $i:

```
find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec wc -l {} \; | tr -s " " | cut -d " " -f 2
```

i is a list of directories and the upper code is in a foreach cycle
the output of this are number how many lines has the actual file, now i just have to sum them

But i need to sum the lenght for all files in the directory

tried to add the line to some variable:

```
@ variable = (`find $i...`)
```

but it gave me badly formed number error.

anybody has an idea how to solve this? im desperate, trying to do it for whole day,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `wc` command will add up the line counts for you, so this:

```
wc -l $i/* | tail -n 1
```

will very nearly do what you want; the differences are that it doesn't eliminate things other than plain files, and it doesn't count "hidden" files whose names start with `.`.  This:

```
wc -l `find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f -print` /dev/null | tail -n 1
```

should do what you want.  (The addition of `/dev/null` is a trick to handle the case where there are no files in the directory.) The output is going to be something like

```
    210 total
```

(with leading spaces); you can capture the number using `awk`:

```
wc -l `find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f -print` /dev/null | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'
```

If you want to use the shell to add up the numbers yourself, this should do it:

```
@ total = 0
foreach file ( `find $i -maxdepth 1 -type f` )
    @ total += `wc -l < $file`
end
```

though for very large directories you might run into a limit on the length of a command line.

Finally, I feel obligated to let you know that csh and tcsh are not good shells for programming. Their syntax is highly irregular. I've been using them for decades, and I still have to resort to trial and error to find out whether a particular construct is going to work. I strongly suggest learning `sh` and/or `bash` instead. See [this article](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot).

Comment: Thanks, the last one was the best solution for me, almost whole day was thinking how t odo it, the first on is very interesting and the second and third doesnt work, they never end looks like they cycle.

Comment: Im just started with unix and shell scripting and at our university we are in tw ogroups, the experienced ones using bash and the newcomers to unix and we use tcsh

Comment: @Ricsie: Newcomers are being taught tcsh for scripting? That's a really bad idea.

Comment: Yes, we could choose bash(2), but the course which has bash is going much faster and skipped the basics, so we usually choose all tcsh, but after the course i would like to get more experiences with bash, thanks a lot again, you helped me a lot to move in my project :-)

Comment: @Ricsie: Glad I could help. IMHO there should not be a course teaching csh or tcsh scripting *at all*.

Comment: If i knew that before i would better learn hard and go to bash class, also they use vim and we use joe editor, i heard vim is better to know. I thought cshell is a classic unix shell, but yes i first met unix just a couple of weeks ago maybe a month haha